# Android Studio - утеряны шаблоны Code Templates

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста у меня вот такая беда:
Установил Android Studio, (при этом переустанавливал и раньше её) и при создании интерфейса или класса у меня выходит ошибка ***Unable to parse template "class/Interface"***. Я иду по пути: **Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates** и вижу что во всех шаблонах пусто! Я нашёл шаблон для класса, класс теперь создаётся а вот интерфейс нет - не могу найти шаблон. Соответственно и для остальных **Code Templates** я шаблоны найти тоже не могу. Я 100 раз переустанавливал программу и всё-равно всё тоже самое, раньше такого не было! Сейчас если я даже вручную пишу шаблон для **Class**, то после перезапуска программы шаблон стирается! С чем это связано подскажите?

[image: Вот что выдаёт при создании класса]
[image: А вот что показано в шаблонах]

Я проверил файлы по пути, ***AndroidStudio2.3\config\fileTemplates\internal*** там есть один файл **Class.java**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эти шаблоны должны лежать по пути %USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio2.3\config\fileTemplates\internal . Проверьте есть ли сами файлы и права на доступ к ним

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, я удалял переустанавливал. Стирал всё, даже джаву.

Comment: Переместите эту директорию .AndroidStudio2.3 и запустите студию.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, сейчас попробую вновь.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, удалил папку. Программа запустила мастер настроек, итог: Всё так же пусто

Comment: теперь по пути ...fileTemplates\internal - там стало пусто!

Comment: Может кто поделится этим файликом?

Comment: @woesss, там нету файлов. Папка .fileTemplates полностью пустая

Comment: При запуске AS в лог падает эта ошибка `FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/lib/idea.jar` а сам файл такой есть по этому пути

Comment: На вновь созданном проекте тоже самое? Invalidate Caches / Restart не помогает? Тогда может сам установочный файл студии повреждён(сбой сети при скачивании или антивирус чудит)?

Comment: @woesss абсолютно верно! С пакетами установки всё в порядке, скачивал с офф. сайта. Invalidate Caches / Restart не помогает, раз 50 уже пробовал. Блин у меня работа встала из-за этого недодела. Прошу Вас, помогите

Comment: Я понимаю что с офф.сайта, но всё же файл мог быть повреждён при загрузке.Сравните хэш-суммы (на странице загрузки указаны). Если в зипе качали можно архиватором протестировать. А если траффик не "золотой" можно и сразу перекачать. Просто другой причины воспроизведения одной и той же ошибки после полной переустановки не представляется. И Вас студия надеюсь не превью?

Comment: @woesss ну так я просто раньше ставил и всё было отлично. Пакет я не менял. Сейчас попробую скачать....но что то мне подсказывает что моя винда шалит...

Comment: Машину перезагружали надеюсь?

Comment: @woesss, похоже что и в правду. Ошибка в пакетах установки. Сейчас скачал новую версию без SDK, удалил старую версию, и запустил скачаный софт. Теперь всё отлично!) Шаблоны есть)

Comment: Вы мой спаситель) А что может случится со старыми пакетами?

Comment: Да много чего. Например, худший вариант: если диску не первый год система могла обнаружить битый сектор и перенести его, но часть данных была потеряна, тогда стоит всерьёз задуматься о бэкапах данных и покупке нового.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сегодня после обновления с Android Studio 2.3 на Android Studio 3.0.1 внезапно произошла та же ошибка > **Unable to parse template "class/Interface"**. Exe-шник скачивал свежий с офф.сайта. Чистая установка может выручить ситуацию, но на просторах интернета я нашёл проще метод, как эту проблему исправить:

*Открыть папку и файл с установленной средой по пути* **:**
 ~ *Android Studio\bin\studio.exe* **.vmoptions**

*Добавить в предпоследнию строку следущий код:* `-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false`
В итоге у нас:

```
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=
-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false
-da
```

Оригинальная ссылка на статью [Entry fileTemplates//Singleton.java.ft not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775679/entry-filetemplates-singleton-java-ft-not-found)